# Setting up Varnish on CentOS 7, Nginx and PHP-FPM with SSL

Tags: magento, nginx, centos7, varnish

I've not used Varnish before but I need to install it on our Magento site to help speed things up.

I've found lots of articles on how to set up Varnish on Centos 7, PHP-FPM etc but none that runs with CentOS7, Nginx, PHP-FPM **AND** SSL.
As I understand it, Varnish doesn't natievly work with SSL so you need to do some Nginx jiggery-pokery to get things working.
This is also a multi-store Magento site so that adds another layer of complication.

Does anybody have any information to help with this?

Comment: Instead of NGINX(SSL) - Varnish - NGINX stack, you may want to use Hitch for SSL, because it can communicate to Varnish using PROXY protocol and thus seamlessly deliver client IP address to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you my own Nginx config files to make this works. This is Debian 9 not Centos 7, but Nginx should works in the same way.

If someone have a better configuration, or advices, i will listen carfully... I am a Magento dev not a system admin. I have a lot to learn about Nginx & Varnish.

Here, Varnish is listening **port 6081**.

1. I created a **Varnish Proxy** to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP varnish. In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy.website.com` :

```sh
## HTTPS termination & Varnish proxy
server {

  server_name en.website.com fr.website.com es.website.com de.website.com;

  listen 443 ssl http2;


  access_log /var/www/log/varnish-proxy.log;
  error_log /var/www/log/varnish-proxy.error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/conf/ssl.conf;

  keepalive_timeout 300s;

  location / {
    #BYPASS VARNISH
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:611;
    #VARNISH ENABLED
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header X-Secure on;
    proxy_set_header X-Magento-Debug 1;
  }
}
```

2. Then, my vhost in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/website.com` :

```sh
upstream fastcgi_backend { # USE YOUR OWN CONFIG HERE
   # use tcp connection
   # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
   # or socket
   server   unix:/var/run/php7.1-fpm.sock; 
}
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE_GLOBAL { # USE YOUR OWN CONFIG HERE
    en.website.com en;
    fr.website.com fr;
    es.website.com es;
    de.website.com de;
}

# Redirect to https
server {
  server_name en.website.com fr.website.com es.website.com de.website.com;
  listen 80;

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }

  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect to https
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 611;

  set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento;
  set $MAGE_MODE developer;
  set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
  set $MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE_GLOBAL;

  set $HTTPS_FORWARD on;
  set $FPM_USER www-data;

  access_log /var/www/log/website.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/log/website.com.error.log error;

  include /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

3. Enable your vhosts

```sh
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy.website.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/website.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

4. Restart nginx. `-t` will test your configuration files, `-s reload` will reload Nginx config without interupting the service :

```sh
nginx -t && nginx -s reload
```

**EDIT :**

5. Edit Varnish startup config :

   - CentOS 6: `/etc/sysconfig/varnish`
   - CentOS 7: `/etc/varnish/varnish.params`
   - Debian/Ubuntu: `/etc/default/varnish`

```sh
...
## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,1024m \
             -p workspace_backend=256 \
             -p http_resp_hdr_len=42000"
...
```

6. In Magento admin :

   - set `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Caching Application` to **Varnish Cache**
   - Now clic on the new "Varnish Configuration" Filed
   - Set `Access list` and `Backend host` to **localhost**. I don't know what are the other options.
   - Save configuration changes
   - Clic `Export VCL` according to your Varnish's version
7. Upload the Magento VCL

   - Backup the default varnish VCL `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` to `/etc/varnish/default.vcl.bkp`
   - Put the magento VCL in a new `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` file.
   - Edit the first lines :

```sh
vcl 4.0; import std;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "404";
}

backend mywebsite {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "611";
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.http.host ~ "website.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = mywebsite;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }

...
```

8. Sometimes, you will have to handle special cases like disabling Varnish for some URLs.

   - Go to your `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` and edit this like you need. It's quite obscur the first time you see the VCL, but in the end it's not that hard to understand.
   - Or edit your varnish proxy that way :

```sh
## HTTPS termination & Varnish proxy
server {
...
  location ^~ /sitemap {
    #BYPASS VARNISH
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:611;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header X-Secure on;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Antoine, many thanks for this.  I'm going to try and get it running today.  Could you please also share your Varnish config?  Thanks again.

Comment: I add my Varnish config too. Hope it helps

Comment: Legend.  Thank you so much for your help.